# Creating Unique Array Pairs In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I came across a kind of a puzzle today during my coding.
I wanted to share and get help from you.

I make a query in to the MySql Database and get results as in an array.
So I have an output like this:

```
 $rows=array(n) { // for each n value elements can have different values
    ["val1"] => string(3) "abc"
    ["val2"] => string(3) "def"
    ["val3"] => string(3) "ghi"
    ["val4"] => string(3) "jkl"
}
```

So let's say n=4 for instance and i need to create unique pairs that same numbers of pair do not occur in the queue.
What I need is as in the example:

```
n= 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Pairs I need to get:

```
1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4
```

I need to avoid the pairs like `2-1. 3-1, 4-1, 3-2, 4-2, 4-3 and 1-1, 2-2, 3-3, 4-4`.
For Every Pair, I will Check if this pair of arrays are equal.
How can I do that?

Comment: do you want to end up with... `abc-def, abc-ghi, abc-jkl, def-ghi, def-jkl, ghi-jkl`..?

Comment: nope, i just need to get the unique pairs to check if these two arrays have to same values, so i need to get tem paired up once so it does not check it two times.

Comment: so........ you literally want, given n=4, just this?  `1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4`

Comment: n can be any number, so i need to create a logic that does this pars without duplicate regardless what is the value of 'n'.

Comment: right, n can be whatever, but if n is 4, you want just a list of those pairs of numbers?  (I'm confused at what you want)

Comment: yes i can use that too.

Comment: @Justin Does my solution for you work?

Comment: @Arian, testing, give me one minute please. thank you.

Comment: @Justin I updated my answer a bit, so it is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$n = 4;

for($i = 1; $i<=$n; $i++)
    for($x = 1; $x<=$n; $x++)
        if($i != $x && !isset($array[$x][$i]))
            $array[$i][$x] = '';


//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($array);
//echo '</pre>';
?>
```

to output use

```
<?php

for($i = 1; $i<=$n; $i++)
    for($x = 1; $x<=$n; $x++)
        if(isset($array[$i][$x]))
            echo $i.'-'.$x.', ';

?>
```

which would be:

if `$n = 4`

> 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4,

if `$n = 10`

> 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 1-10, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 2-10, 3-4, 3-5, 3-6, 3-7, 3-8, 3-9, 3-10, 4-5, 4-6, 4-7, 4-8, 4-9, 4-10, 5-6, 5-7, 5-8, 5-9, 5-10, 6-7, 6-8, 6-9, 6-10, 7-8, 7-9, 7-10, 8-9, 8-10, 9-10,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works with no problem. i get all the necessary pairs with this and no duplicates.  if the value of n is 100 Do you think it would take too long?

Comment: @Justin: 1. what if you try? 2. what if you *calculate* ?

Comment: @Justin it shouldn't take long with a 100, I just did it instantaneously... just use the updated answer, as I don't set the array to `= 'YES'`, I only set it to `''`

Comment: @zerkms i did not understand what you meant, can you explain what you mean? thank you.

Comment: @Arian i am positive on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the array and I just remove the elements once all the pairs have been made, probably there's a better solution using only for's

```
  $n = 5;
$array = array("abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno");
$r_temp = $array;
$r_result = array();
foreach($array as $r){
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $n-1){
        array_push($r_result,$r_temp[0].$r_temp[$i+1]);
        $i++;
    }
    $n--;
    array_shift($r_temp); //Remove the first element since all the pairs are used
}

print_r($r_result);
```

Output would be

```
Array ( [0] => abcdef [1] => abcghi [2] => abcjkl [3] => abcmno [4] => defghi [5] => defjkl [6] => defmno [7] => ghijkl [8] => ghimno [9] => jklmno )
```

Comment: this is not what i am trying to get. my target is to make pairs of the element identifying numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, however it looks like a good example of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

First, a direct answer to your question:

```
$n = 4;
$pairs = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; ++$i) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j <= $n; ++$j) {
        $pairs[] = [$i, $j];
    }
}
```

(You can check it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e66ced29d6810b68649a37064131525245806274)).

**However,** if I understand correctly what you were looking for, it is easier to do so directly with and SQL query:

```
SELECT mycolumn, COUNT(*) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY mycolumn HAVING total > 1;
```

This query will return all repeated entries of column `mytable.mycolumn` and number of appearances.